# Ruby on Rails on existing Sql Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I'm sorry about this question.  I see all the other questions with very similar titles as this.  I promise I've read them over and followed what they've suggested but haven't had luck or am not hitting the same problem they are hitting.  It's discouraging because so many have said that RoR is incredibly easy to get going and to code with.

I'm on a windows box.  I've gem installed activerecord-sqlserver-adapter and tiny_tds.  I try to `rake db:migrate` it says

```
rake aborted!
Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter'.  Make sure 
that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid.
```

Here's my trace:

```
    Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter'. Make sure
    that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other th
an 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to
 the Gemfile.
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:56:in `resolve_hash_co
nnection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:46:in `resolve_string_
connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:30:in `spec'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_handling.rb:39:in `establish_connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/railtie.rb:176:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/act
ive_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/act
ive_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/act
ive_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/act
ive_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/act
ive_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/railtie.rb:174:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:30:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in
each_strongly_connected_component'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connec
ted_component_from'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strong
ly_connected_component'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connec
ted_component'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/ap
plication.rb:215:in `initialize!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/ra
iltie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
C:/Sites/blog/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/ap
plication.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/ap
plication.rb:250:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.r
b:236:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.r
b:236:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.r
b:231:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.r
b:231:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.r
b:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.r
b:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.r
b:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.r
b:195:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.r
b:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.r
b:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.r
b:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.r
b:161:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:100:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:78:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:75:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in
`<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

And here's how I have my database.yml set up:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  database: db.url.com/database
  username: username
  password: password
```

Is there something silly I'm missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that adapter added in your Gemfile? If so, did you build with `bundle install`?

Comment: @Teeg I see my GemFile by doing gem list, yeah?  If so, yes, I see sqlserver in the list.

Comment: @Teeg As for bundle install...no I don't think I did that.  How is it done?

Comment: Before running 'rake db:migrate', run 'bundle install'. Then, if 'rake db:migrate' still doesn't work, try the command 'bundle exec rake db:migrate'. Let us know how you go.

Comment: @Aarmora First question, no that just shows you what gems you have presently installed. In rails, there is a specific file called `Gemfile`. Open that up and insert the line `gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'` (doesn't matter where, I usually put DB stuff towards the top, but placement is irrelevant). For the second question, in the root of your project directory, just execute the `bundle install` line that I wrote. This will install all the gems with their proper versions for you and set up appropriate meta information, etc. Then try to run your server again.

Comment: @joshua.paling I did it and it's throwing the same error.  During `bundle install` it's no listing my sqlserver nor my activerecord-sqlserver-adapter in the using list and when I say `bundle show sqlserver` it says that it cannot find the gem.

Comment: @Teeg Boo yah.  Progress, I think!  I definitely wasn't looking at that GemFile.  I added it in and ran bundle install.  Now when I run `rake db:migrate` it's still throwing an error but this time it says `undefined method `add_order!' for class `Class'`.  That sounds like something wrong with my db stuff.

Comment: @Aarmora Good stuff. Yeah that sounds like some other error entirely now, which is good (in a way).